# Is there any way to use xtermjs parsersers in Python directly without frontend rendering?

Tags: javascript, python, pty, xtermjs

I want to handle ansi characters of python pty with xtermjs.
As I know there is no ansi parser better than xtermjs, xtermjs can handle interactive programs like nano and htop but others can't.
so how can I parse and handle ansi charachters with xtermjs in python ?

Currently I have a hacky solution but its slow and needs run java script:

I make a HTML(contains code of xtermjs) with python, something like this :

```
const term = new Terminal({
    convertEol:true,
});
term.open(document.getElementById("terminal"));

term.write(`[?2004h[?1049h[22;0;0t[1;24r(B[m[4l[?7h[39;49m[?1h=[?1h=[?25l[39;49m(B[m[H[2J[22;35H(B[0;7m[ New File ](B[m[H(B[0;7m  GNU nano 4.8                         a1.txt                                   [1;79H(B[m
    [23d(B[0;7m^G(B[m Get Help  (B[0;7m^O(B[m Write Out (B[0;7m^W(B[m Where Is  (B[0;7m^K(B[m Cut Text  (B[0;7m^J(B[m Justify   (B[0;7m^C(B[m Cur Pos
    [24d(B[0;7m^X(B[m Exit[14G(B[0;7m^R(B[m Read File (B[0;7m^\(B[m Replace   (B[0;7m^U(B[m Paste Text(B[0;7m^T(B[m To Spell  (B[0;7m^_(B[m Go To Line
    [22d[2d[39;49m(B[m[?12l[?25h`)

term.selectAll()
parsed = term.getSelection()
console.debug(parsed)
```

Then in Python I run this file and capture console logs with selenium!
In this way I can get a pretty output of that ugly string passed to `term.write()`

P.S : I can't use socket for communication.
I appreciate for a better and faster solution.

Comment: Several ways come to my mind: xtermjs-headless with nodejs (does not need a full browser stack); write a binding against libvte (maybe possible with ctypes); check if pexpect has a good enough terminal emulator lib included (can be run directly from within python).

Comment: @jerch I don't want use nodejs for backend. second option seems complicated to me. I don't think pexpect has anything special about that.

Comment: https://github.com/pexpect/pexpect/blob/master/pexpect/ANSI.py